# Setup SMTP settings for sending mail in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've followed the [following tutorial](http://l4u.github.io/articles/create-a-rails-4-site-with-contact-us-form/#booting-rails-server-with-guard) to create a contact form.

Everything was fine, but as tutorial says `For real e-mail delivery, you should set up SMTP in the environment settings.` how can I set up SMTP?

As Suggested in [this](http://andr.esmejia.com/posts/23-using-gmail-s-smtp-server-to-send-mail-from-rails) link I created and edited the smtp_settings.rb; But No luck at all. It still doesnot send the email to the real user.

## smtp_settings.rb

```
if Rails.env.production?
  Gitlab::Application.config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    user_name: "myaccount@gmail.com",
    password: "abcpassword",
    domain: "mail.google.com",
    authentication: :login,
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

It may be because your `smtp_settings.rb` file isn't being found by Rails, or that the `delivery_method` line isn't being recognised..

Try moving the file to `/config/initializers/smtp_settings.rb` if it isn't there already, and changing the contents slightly to

```
if Rails.env.production?
  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    address:              "smtp.gmail.com",
    port:                 587,
    user_name:            "myaccount@gmail.com",
    password:             "abcpassword",
    domain:               "mail.google.com",
    authentication:       :login,
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
end
```

It could also be that the settings are only applied for **production**, if you're trying this out locally in development you'll need to remove the first line `if Rails...` and the last line `end` like so..

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  address:              "smtp.gmail.com",
  port:                 587,
  user_name:            "myaccount@gmail.com",
  password:             "abcpassword",
  domain:               "mail.google.com",
  authentication:       :login,
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

After any changes to this file you'll need to restart your rails server or rails console session for the changes to take effect.